# MAUI Text Entry on Complete not Working - Possible Work around?

Tags: event-handling, maui

I'm trying to use text entry on maui to fire an event when completed. I have set the "Completed" event to a handler and it works correctly on windows. But on Android I have no joy, the event just isn't firing.

I realise there is a bug in Maui which is preventing this. But it looks like the problem was discovered in August? It's a fairly basic thing, well at least it appears to be on the face of things.

What is the best work around for this? The only thing I can think is by using the textchanged event instead of completed. This works correctly, but then i have to bodge it by doing this sort of thing:

```
if (entry1.Text.EndsWith("@"))
{
//Then string is complete, so need to fire correct event
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Complete String Detected");
}
```

This works and I can use it since I'm awaiting for input from a barcode scanner, so I can set the last terminating character to whatever I want. In this case I set it to a @. I can't figure out a way to detect the return key being pressed.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: if you think this is a known bug, then linking to the bug report would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue on the github about the [Entry.Completed and Entry.ReturnCommand not executed](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8960).
This [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8960#issuecomment-1220584622) shows the cause and the workaround about this problem.

> detect the return key being pressed

In addition, I can't understand the problem. I have created a sample to test. The Entry.Completed event will call when I pressed the enter key. I don't kown the return key you mentioned is what. But you can use the `IOnKeyListener` for the android to detect any key being pressed.

1. Create a Listener class in the /Platform/Android:

```
public class MyKeyListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnKeyListener
    {
        public bool OnKey(global::Android.Views.View v, [GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            var edittext = v as AppCompatEditText;
            if (keyCode == Keycode.Enter && e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down )
            //I used the Entry key as the example, you can use any other key you want to replace it.
            {
                edittext.ClearFocus();
                edittext.SetBackgroundColor(Color.GreenYellow);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

2. And in the page.xml:

```
<Entry Completed="Entry_Completed" x:Name="entry"/>
```

3. Set the listener to the entry by overriding the `OnHandlerChanged()` in the page.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
        (entry.Handler.PlatformView as AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText).SetOnKeyListener(new MauiAppTest.Platforms.Android.MyKeyListener());
#endif
    }
```

You can also set the listener with the handler. Finally, you can try both the method above and the workaround in the issue on the github.